Dehn function of a finite presentation of a finite group
I am studying Dehn functions and stumbled upon a 'popular' exercise on Dehn functions that I could not crack.  For example, it appears as Exercise 3 of Timothy Riley's book section (Office Hour 8: Dehn Functions) in Office Hours with a Geometric Group Theorist and Exercise 3.1.1 (i) in Martin R. Bridson's book section The geometry of the word problem in Invitations to geometry and topology. It is also mentioned as the first example on the wikipedia page on Dehn functions.

Show that the Dehn function $\delta_{\langle S \mid R \rangle}(n)$ of a finite presentation $\langle S \mid R \rangle$ of a finite group $G$ is always bounded above by $C\cdot n$ for some constant $C$.

I have already found a geometric solution: the Cayley 2-complex has only a finite number of faces, say $C > 0$. A freely reduced word representing the identity in $G$ can be viewed as a loop in the Cayley 2-complex based at $e$.  If it is simple, it cannot pass an edge more than once and so must have an Area that is bounded by the number of faces $C$. If it is not simple and $\lvert w \rvert_S \leq n$, the loop can be written as the concatenation of at most $n$ simple loops and so it has an Area of an most $C \cdot n$.
But I would also like to have an algebraic solution (preferably 'straight from the definition')  as it is mentioned so early in Prof. Riley's text (before the introduction of 2-complexes) and it has eluded me thusfar.
For what I have tried: Given $w \in F(S)$ freely reduced with $w =_G e$. Since $G$ is finite I had hoped that we could somehow use the fact that there are a finite number of words, say $g_1, \ldots, g_K$, in $F(S)$ that together represent $G$.  But I suppose it is not true that we can write $w = \prod_{j=1}^L g_{i_j}\cdot r_j \cdot g_{i_j}^{-1}$ where $r_j \in R$?
I do not really see how to 'get it right.'
Thank you in advance!

I think what you want is Van Kampen diagrams and the Van Kampen lemma.
Your post is a little vague on this point, but presumably your proof gives a construction that inputs a loop of length $\le n$ in the Cayley graph and outputs a Van Kampen diagram for that disc of area $\le C \cdot n$. If you do actually have such a construction, then you should be able to look at the output diagram and directly convert it into the equation you desire.
In general, the Van Kampen lemma gives a procedure that converts an arbitrary Van Kampen diagram into an equation. This is all laid out in the proof of Van Kampen's Lemma, which you can read about at the above link (or in any combinatorial group theory book).

Thank you for the response.
Considering how early the exercise 2.9 appears in Prof. Riley’s text (https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~riley/papers/What_is_a_Dehn_function/What_is_a_Dehn_function.pdf), I believe a more elementary straightforward ‘combinatorial’ argument should be possible, preferable straight from the definition.  But indeed, if I flesh out my argument better, I might be able to translate it in algebra terms, as you point out.

I think you are missing my point. Van Kampen's lemma is just a name that is put on an elementary combinatorial argument. What you need even to apply Van Kampen's lemma is an explicit description of the items that you left overly vague in your post: precisely how do you "get an area that is bounded by the number of faces $C$", as you wrote? If you can describe that with rigor then, with an added cominatorial argument, you will have your proof.
